# nextjs/react - "document is not defined" / "cannot read properties of null (reading 'useEffect')"

Tags: reactjs, web, next.js

I just got a website template which I'm now editing and now I want to hide the scrollbar on the right side. Initially what I did was to add the line `"document.body.style.overflow='hidden'"`, however this didn't really work, as it showed after the initial edit, but after manually refreshing the page the first error raised: "document is not defined".
After that I was looking for a solution, which is where I stumbled upon using `"useEffect"`. Now I'm stuck with the error "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useEffect').

Here's the code starting on the very first line:

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import Image from 'next/image';

import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react';
import SwiperCore, { Mousewheel, Scrollbar } from 'swiper';

SwiperCore.use([Mousewheel]);

import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';

useEffect(() => document.body.style.overflow= 'hidden');

// document.body.style.overflow= 'hidden';  <- initial try; "document not defined"

import bannerImg1 from "../../public/images/slider/most_slide_1.jpg";
import bannerImg2 from "../../public/images/slider/most_slide_2.jpg";

const sliderOption = {
    pagination: {
      el: '.swiper-pagination',
      clickable: true,
      type: 'progressbar',
    },
    navigation: {
      nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
      prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev'
    },
    loop: true,
    spaceBetween: 0,
    slidesPerView: '1',
    parallax: true,
    speed: 700,
    breakpoints: {
        0: {
          slidesPerView: 1,
        },
    }
}

const HomeSlider = () => {
    
    const swiperRef = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (swiperRef.current) {
          swiperRef.current, sliderOption;
        }
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="banner-horizental">
```

etc.

And following error message on my localhost:
[Server Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNc7p.png)

Initially I tried to use "document.body.style.overflow='hidden' but I soon realised I had to switch to "useEffect", however I can't get it to work.

Edit: I just realised myself. It works now...

Comment: You can't use a `useEffect` outside of a component.
And to use `useEffect, useState` and so on, you nee to declare `'use client'` at the first line.

Comment: **useEffect** runs before DOM creation. That's why it returns **null**.   
useLayoutEffect is a version of useEffect that fires before the browser repaints the screen.  
**useLayoutEffect(()=>{ 
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'red'
})**